# How pass json as parameter to aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-10, aws-cli, aws-glue

I am trying to update crawler using this command:

```
aws glue update-crawler --name my-crawler --configuration '{"Version":1.0,"CrawlerOutput":{"Partitions":{"AddOrUpdateBehavior":"InheritFromTable"}}}' --region us-west-2
```

As described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/update-crawler.html)

Instead of update I got:

```
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the UpdateCrawler operation: Crawler configuration not valid: Error parsing JSON: Received JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'). Check that your JSON is well formed. For more information about the crawler configuration structure, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling.html.
```

The [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) tells me that json is ok.

What is wrong? How pass json as parameter for aws cli?

cli is used under windows 10

Comment: Try this 
`aws glue update-crawler --name my-crawler --configuration {"Version":1.0,"CrawlerOutput":{"Partitions":{"AddOrUpdateBehavior":"InheritFromTable"}}} --region us-west-2`

Comment: `Received JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('V' (code 86)): was expecting double-quote to start field name` :(

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the quotes under Windows:

```
aws glue update-crawler --name my-crawler --configuration "{\"Version\":1.0,\"CrawlerOutput\":{\"Partitions\":{\"AddOrUpdateBehavior\":\"InheritFromTable\"}}}" --region us-west-2
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you have to do some "special" escaping, which I've learned the hard way. Take the following JSON snippet...

```
{ "#t": "timestamp" }`
```

Here's how you'd enter it on Windows...

**DOS**

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name MyTable --region "us-east-1" --profile dev --projection-expression "failureKey, #t" --expression-attribute-names "{ ""#t"": ""timestamp"" }"
```

For Powershell, it's a little different...

**Powershell**

```bsh
aws dynamodb scan --table-name "MyTable" --region "us-east-1" --profile "dev" --projection-expression "failureKey, #t" --expression-attribute-names '{ \"#t\": \"timestamp\" }'
```

Used an example with a shorter JSON snippet, but you get the idea. Apply the same concept to your string based on the shell your using.